# How to find button with Selenium by its text inside (Python)?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have the following three buttons that I can't figure out how to grab the text that is inside of them (e.g Outliers). I tried `browser.find_element_by_link_text("Outliers").click()`, but got "Unable to locate element" error. How can I do it?

[image]

Answer (score 81, accepted):

See: [find_element_by_* commands are deprecated in selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69875125/find-element-by-commands-are-deprecated-in-selenium)

In newer versions of selenium try:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[text()="Outliers"]')
```

older versions of selenium:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()="Outliers"]')
```

To update ALL of the older versions I found a nifty regex here, and then just fixup the import:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/70586710/2026508

Comment: Update: find_element_by_xpath is deprecated now and one should use the equivalent `browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[normalize-space()="Outliers"]')` (need to `from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By`)

Answer (score 28):

**There are two ways :**

1. By using **text()** method:

`browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'//button[text()="Outliers"]')`

2. By using **normalize-space()** method:

`browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[normalize-space()="Outliers"]')`

**Note :** It is always **better to use normalize-space()** method as it will work even if there are **spaces present** at the start of your text or at the end of text, because normalize-space() method **trim the left and right** side spaces

For More information on [Normalize-space()](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/normalize-space-method-pritam-maske/)

Comment: Thanks for the tip with normalize-space(), this was often an issue with the other solution for me. Just one update, find_element_by_xpath is deprecated now and one should use the equivalent `browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[normalize-space()="Outliers"]')` (need to `from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By`)

Answer (score 17):

Try this XPath:

`"//button[@class='three-state-item btn btn-default'][.='Outliers']"`.

Comment: Thank you! It worked. I am accepting the other answer only because it looks cleaner.

Comment: using `.` instead of `text()` is actually more reliable because it will work even if there are several text nodes inside the element (it would concatenate them)

Comment: This method is the only answer that worked for my usage.

Answer (score -2):

This is the solution that worked for me:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

CHROME_DRIVER_PATH = Your Driver Path
USERNAME = YOUR USERNAME
PASSWORD = YOUR PASSWORD
SIMILAR_ACCOUNT = "idogsplanet"

class InstaFollower:
    def __init__(self, driver_path):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path)

    def login(self):
        self.driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/")
        time.sleep(3)
        username = self.driver.find_element_by_name("username")
        username.send_keys(USERNAME)
        password = self.driver.find_element_by_name("password")
        password.send_keys(PASSWORD)
        time.sleep(2)
        login = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="loginForm"]/div/div[3]/button/div')
        login.click()

    def find_followers(self):
        time.sleep(5)
        self.driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/" + SIMILAR_ACCOUNT + "/followers")
        followers = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/header/section/ul/li[2]/a')
        followers.click()
        time.sleep(1)

    def follow(self):
        all_buttons = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//button[normalize-space()="Follow"]')
        modal = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[5]/div/div/div[2]')
        for button in all_buttons:
            if button.text != "Follow":
                pass
            else:
                button.click()
                time.sleep(2)
        time.sleep(10)
        self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight", modal)
        self.follow()

bot = InstaFollower(CHROME_DRIVER_PATH)
bot.login()
bot.find_followers()
bot.follow()
```