# Selenium Python find button with <button type="button" class="size-grid-dropdown size-grid-button" data-qa="size-dropdown">AB 12</button>

Tags: python, html, selenium, class, button

i'm trying to find with selenium in python a button in a website and the button identify is:
AB 12

I'm trying with this code but all can't find the button...

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(@class, '.size-grid-dropdown .size-grid-button') and contains(.,'AB 12)]")

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[span[text()="AB 12"]')

driver.find_element_by_link_text("AB 12")
```

the problem is: i have a lot of button with same class but different AB 12 / AB 23 / AB 34...

How can i find a precisely button?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please post the DOM screenshot. so that we can try to check for some other attributes too.

Comment: find all by class => you'll get a list of buttons => loop through => check if text is "AB 12" . there is no other unique identity for the button as per the DOM you've given

Comment: Does `//button[text()="AB 12"]` work? It's a modified version of the second one you tried, without the span.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Presuming the id of the button is AB 12, the code you want is:
>
> driver.find_element_by_id('AB 12')
>
> you can see this answer for a similar query: >[How to use find_element_by_id() in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6481973/how-to-use-find-element-by-id-in-python)
>   or read the docs for the same here:
>   https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#locate-elements-by

In hindsight i see you want to find a button element with the text "AB 12"
the correct code for that would be:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()="AB 12"]')
```

You can check this similar query for more variations:
[How to find button with Selenium by its text inside (Python)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49906237/how-to-find-button-with-selenium-by-its-text-inside-python)

Comment: Hi, I see you used the code inside the blockquote , that would be incorrect for your question , i kept it for context, try the code at the end of the answer, i.e
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()="AB 12"]')

Comment: Yeah that work...

Thanks so much, I've been trying for a long time...

Correct Answer!